# how to render common variables from app.js to all routes in express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

In my Node.js application some variables that render or every route are common.There are around 4-5 variables which render on every route. And I have around 20 routes.

Currently I am doing passing those variables in every route in `res.render`

Is there a method by which I can pass these common variables in some place '(eg:app.js)` which is being used by every route, so that I can clean up my code a bit.

I use `express.js` for node and `handlebars` for template.

EDIT:I think I should explain a bit more

```
res.render('abc', {
                        commonitem1: 'one',
                        commonitem2: 'two',
                        ...
                   });

-------------------------------------
another route
res.render('xyz', {
                        commonitem1: 'one',
                        commonitem2: 'two',
                        ...
                   });
```

I want to avoid this repeating in my every routes and want to render it from a common place.

Comment: I think you can use this: `app.set("someOptions", "value"); `  and retrieve with `app.get("someOption");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For session or request dependent values you can store those common values in a global variable and then use them directly in res.render. To do that you have following options

- Use app.use to store values :

In your app.js add a middleware which does this for you. Remember to write this middleware before any other routes you define because middleware functions are executed sequentially.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.items = "Value";
    next();
});
//your routes follow
app.use(‘/’, home);
```

In your routes you can place `items` directly in res.render like:

```
res.render('layout', {title: 'My awesome title',view: 'home', item :res.locals.items });
```

- Use express-session to store values :

If you have express-session installed you can save some data in `req.session.item` and place them in any route like:

```
res.render('layout', {title: 'My awesome title',view: 'home', item :req.session.items });
```

Comment: My Issue is in not getting value in every route. I am getting it from a global file where i set common variables. But for getting the value in my template I am passing it in every `res.render` of every route. I want to avoid it and do it from one common place.

Comment: I understand your issue; you want some common elements, like sidebar menu, in your layouts to get generated once be used in multiple pages without re-requiring values. So something like, rendering 'homepage' summons 'sidebar' which fetches its required values and gets embedded in 'homepage'. (Thinking about it)

Comment: Use `res.locals` . Make a function that is called before the routes which require common variables. In that function assign `res.locals.varname` some value. In your layouts you can now use `varname`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals) is what you are looking for - this object is passed to your views for every request and is scoped to each individual request (i.e. each request can have its own version of `res.locals`). There is also `app.locals` which is shared for all requests.

I do not have practical experience with this, but you can either use this object to pass **all** variables to your views or perhaps Express will merge whatever is in `app.locals` with `res.locals` and what you send to the view via `res.render()`. Please test carefully, I have not found relevant information about the merging behaviour in the official docs.

As for populating the `res.locals`, to keep the code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you can write a [custom middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) that populates the object with whatever you need it to have before your actual route logic is executed.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to res.locals :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// I created common func for all routes as below.

function commonRes(layout, req, res) {

  if (req.session.user) {
    res.render(layout, {
      user: req.session.user
      //csrfToken: req.csrfToken() // csrf 
    })

  } else {
    res.render(layout, {
      user: null,
      csrfToken: null
    })
  }

  return res.end()
}



// and apply it to all routes simply as below



app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  return commonRes('index.html', req, res)

})

app.get('/new', (req, res) => {

  return commonRes('new.html', req, res)
})
```

Comment: Can you try to format your code properly when you answer, and explain how the code solves the problem OP is having?

Answer (score -1):

You can create one constants.js file with below code

```
(function (constants) {
    var FetchDataErrorMessage = "Error while fetching User Data";
    var ConnectionErroMessage = "Error while fetching Connecting Server";
    var InsertDataErrorMessage = "Error while inserting User Data";
    var RemoveDataErrorMessage = "Error while removing User Data";
    var UpdateDataErrorMessage = "Error while updating User Data";
})(module.exports);
```

In any file where you need to use those variables you can add below code.

```
var constants = require('constants');    
console.write(constants.RemoveDataErrorMessage);
```

> Output :- "Error while removing User Data"

Comment: You are not exporting anything... Also note that it is not necessary in Node.js to enclose your modules in [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)s, Node does that for you.